# HTTP message converter of Spring 3.0.5 generate inconsistent object when concurrent request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, concurrency, jaxb

I am following **HTTP message converters** of **spring 3.0.5**, for automatically getting java object at controller level. It works fine for sequential request.

But getting inconsistency in java object when giving concurrent request from REST client on server.I am giving same type of request with some differences in data through REST client.

some internal instance object value came null/empty of request object even exist in XML. (verified through logging at filter level and controller level)

Notice one thing all the time get inconsistency in map (key-value pair) of object. don't know any reason for this.

I am using below environment:

1. Spring 3.0.5
2. HTTP message converters
3. Tomcat 1.6
4. jaxb 2.2

Below are the configuration of xml:

```
    <bean id="messageAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

Controller code are as below:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import com.sfnt.saas.provisioning.service.ProvisioningInterfaceManager;
import com.sfnt.saas.provisioning.util.messages.ContractData;
import com.sfnt.saas.provisioning.util.messages.ContractInfo;

@Controller
public class ProvisioningController {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private ProvisioningInterfaceManager provisioningInterfaceManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/1.0/Contract"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void deployContract(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody ContractData contractData)
            throws RuntimeException {

        ContractInfo contractInfo = null;
        contractInfo = provisioningInterfaceManager
                .deployContract(contractData);
        response.addHeader("Location", request.getRequestURL() + "/"
                + contractInfo.getContract().getContract());
    }
}
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: I don't want to synchronize my code, it will hog application performance, as this is multitenant supported application with multiple database.

Comment: The question needs to be updated with a sample of your controller code

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think controller code does not required here, as I **get incomplete object at start of controller**, so controller is not the culprit.

Comment: Can we please see it anyway?

Comment: here sometimes `contractData` came inconsistant, on multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: Does `ProvisioningInterfaceManager` do anything to `contractData` ?

Comment: `ProvisioningInterfaceManager ` just read & extract info to put in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this problem by my own, what i need to do is as below:

As spring provided HttpMessageConverter as `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller` is creating Marshaller/Unmarshaller on each request But not the `JAXBContext` object that is created globally.

So what i need to do - create my own custom HttpMessageConverter and create marshaller/unmarshaller as well as `JAXBContext` on each request, after this my problem goes away .. :) below are the sample code:

**xml:**

```
    <bean id="messageAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbConvertor" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbConvertor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxbConvertor" class="com.sfnt.saas.provisioning.web.JAXBConvertor">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                      <value>com.project.yourclass1</value>
                      <value>com.project.yourclass2</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**CustomConveter:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller;
import org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException;
import org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller;
import org.springframework.oxm.XmlMappingException;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

/**
 * This class will be responsible for providing auto conversion of
 * request/response body.
 * 
 * <h1>Note:</h1>
 * <p>
 * There is need to create custom converter as
 * <code>spring provided converter is
 * generating inconsistent data object in unmarshaling when concurrent request
 * came.</code>
 * <p>
 * In spring provided converter there is global JAXBContext is created and used
 * in all marshaling/unmarshaling that create object inconsistency when
 * concurrent request came.
 * 
 * @see Jaxb2Marshaller
 * @author Atul Kumar
 */
public class JAXBConvertor implements Marshaller, Unmarshaller {
    private Class<?>[] classesToBeBound;
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    /**
     * This method will create JAXBContext in each request which is not done in
     * spring provided converter
     */
    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Source source) throws IOException,
            XmlMappingException {
        try {
            javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(getClassesToBeBound()).createUnmarshaller();
            return jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error("Error in unmarshallering xml to object", e);
            throw new UncategorizedMappingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This method will create JAXBContext in each request which is not done in
     * spring provided converter
     */
    @Override
    public void marshal(Object graph, Result result) throws IOException,
            XmlMappingException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(graph.getClass());
            javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext
                    .createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(graph, result);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error("Error in marshallering object to xml", e);
            throw new UncategorizedMappingException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the list of Java classes to be recognized by a newly created
     * JAXBContext. Setting this property or {@link #setContextPath
     * "contextPath"} is required.
     */
    public synchronized void setClassesToBeBound(Class<?>... classesToBeBound) {
        this.classesToBeBound = classesToBeBound;
    }

    /**
     * Return the list of Java classes to be recognized by a newly created
     * JAXBContext.
     */
    public Class<?>[] getClassesToBeBound() {
        return this.classesToBeBound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its compromising performance, please see below link

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/09/jaxbcontext-performance-problem-case.html

Comment: But as per link detail this is default implementation of Spring Converters. bcz of which i was having this issue in concurrent access.

And solve my issue through creating `JAXBContext` on each request, Please see my above comments in solutions.